# How can I make my switch statement case insensitive?

Tags: php

In the following example, sometimes `$var` can be "Value", "value" or even "VALUE".

```
switch ( $var ) {
    case "value":
        // Value and VALUE don't seem to match here.
        break;
}
```

The comparison seems to be case sensitive (only the all-lowercase "value" matches). Is there a way to perform a case-insensitive comparison?

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Use `strtolower($var)` in your switch statement

Comment: `switch (strtolower($var)) { case "value":...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = strtolower($var)
```

And then in the switch cases write all lowercase

Answer (score 3):

Convert your string to lowercase, then compare it to all lowercase strings

```
switch ( strtolower($var) ) {
    case "value":
        // Value and VALUE don't seem to match here.
        break;
}
```