# Needs help on case insensitive for switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case-insensitive

[How can I make my switch statement case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285235/how-can-i-make-my-switch-statement-case-insensitive/33285259) and [Case-insensitive switch-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690186/case-insensitive-switch-case) did not answer my question.

I have tried using the coding switch(strtolower(Q1)) and switch(Q1.toLowerCase()). Both doesn't work.

Can someone help me pls? Thanks.

Below is the coding without using switch(strtolower(Q1)) and switch(Q1.toLowerCase()).

```
(function() {

var defaultAns = 0;

switch(Q1) {

case "Test1": return 1; 

break;

case "Dummy1": return 1; 

break;

default:

return defaultAns;
}

})();
```

Comment: *"Nothing works for me"*: you didn't do what is in those other answers then... The code you share here has no trace of the advise that was given on those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test(q) {
    var defaultAns = 0;
    switch (q.toLowerCase()) {
        case "Test1".toLowerCase():
            return 1;
            break;
        case "Dummy1".toLowerCase():
            return 1;
            break;
        default:
            return defaultAns;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a legend! The other post did not advise to add .toLowerCase() after case "Test1" which explains why their answer did not work for me. Thanks very much Gopi.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert all values to lower case.

```
(function() {
    var defaultAns = 0;
    switch (Q1.toLowerCase()) {
        case "test1":
            return 1;
        case "dummy1":
            return 1;
        default:
            return defaultAns;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Sorry,  but this is clearly a dupe. Did you check the link that the OP mentioned in their question?